# Modifying sys.path

Tags: python, sys.path

PYTHON 3.3
I have my HDD partitioned with programmes on "C" and data on "D" one NTFS and the other fat32. I've downloaded  examples of code from one of the popular manuals onto "D". Running sys.path does not show these. I've looked, but cannot find the sys.path file to permanently add my "path". I can have the sys.path come up in IDLE, but making changes here are only temporary I believe. It is a small irritation to have to "go looking" each time. I'd really appreciate some comments, and apologize if this has already been answered somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you "poke" and "kHr" for your answers. I really appreciate them.

Comment: If an answer helped you to solve your problem [please *accept it*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to mark the question as resolved. In addition, you can upvote answers to express your gratitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the environment variable [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) to adjust the default path Python looks for modules when importing.

Answer (score 0):

For instance, to add the directory /home/me/mypy to the path, just do:

> > import sys
> >
> > sys.path.append("/home/me/mypy")

source:
http://www.johnny-lin.com/cdat_tips/tips_pylang/path.html